# Typelite: dates in DTO gets mapped to Date, but are actually ISO8601 strings

Tags: servicestack, typelite

I use ServiceStack. In my C# DTO I have an attribute

```
    public DateTime Created  { get; set; }
```

which is mapped to TypeScript using TypeLITE http://type.litesolutions.net/

```
interface Instance {
   Created: Date;
```

However, since I do not want to send JavaScript specific date format over the API, I use ISO dates using this ServiceStack setting

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
```

So, I have a mismatch here. One solution is to instead use the Typescript class

```
interface Instance {
   Created: string;
```

and parse the date when used. Where would I put the call Date.parse('iso-date-string')? The ambitious solution is to have the TypeScript class twice, one with string, and one with Date.

In order to make TypeLITE generate string instead of Date for DateTime, what should I do?

The number of classes is rather small, so I can fix them up by hand. But, my idea is that I would have a special API call where the client can download the TypeScript declarations, and then, a complete automated TypeLITE would be much nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a TypeLITE convertor for the `DateTime`:

```cs
TypeScript.Definitions()
    .ForLoadedAssemblies()
    .WithConvertor<DateTime>(t => "string")
```

Comment: Yes. If you are using a C# API and plan to generate the TypeScript interface this is the way to go. (Or you can convert the string values to DateTime on the server side)